# Numerical Solution to an Algebraic Function

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

Basically I am trying to solve an algebraic function of the form y[x]=x^2+5x+7 with some initial conditions and I want to find y[x] in the region where x goes from 1 to 50. What is the right command and syntax to use for this? I am a little confused. I realize that NDSolve is for differential equations, while the format of NSolve does not allow me to enter initial conditions/range? So what's the right command to use.

Comment: As I read your question, all you have to do is evaluate y[x_] := x^2 + 5 x + 7 $\quad$Then you can evaluate y for any numerical value; for example, y[2] will return 21

Answer (score 1):

You *have* the solution for `y[x]`.

```
y[x_] := x^2 + 5 x + 7;
```

There's no such notion of "initial conditions."

Then

```
Plot[y[x], {x, 1, 50}]
```

Comment: You are right, that makes sense. Basically I have a complicated set of Differential Equations; I was trying to start with some simple example to get a grasp of Mathematica. This example is not the right one though as like you said it is already a solution.